# Flask convert Form to Json Errors

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am getting data from wtforms and putting it in a Form object

```
 class CustomerForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, fName, mName, lName, stName, stNo, email):
        self.firstName = fName
        self.middleName = mName
        self.lastName = lName
        self.streetName = stName
        self.streetNo = stNo
        self.email = email
```

I am trying to convert this into a JSON object. I tried the following separately but putting them together below:

```
request.get_json()

json.load(request.data)

json.loads(form, object_hook=form_decoder)
def form_decoder(form):
    if '__type__' in form and form['__type__'] == 'CustomerForm':
        return CustomerForm(form['firstName'], form['middleName'], form['lastName'], form['streetName'],form['streetNo'],form['email'])
    return form
```

I cannot get it into JSON format for some reason. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
print json.dumps(form,  default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Ended up working for me :)